# EmailJS not sending form content in React

Tags: reactjs, email

I have setup emailJS in my on my website for people to send me messages. Everything is going well and the email do send. However, the content of the form does not send in the email.

The name, email address, subject, and message all are blank in the email. My code is below along with a image of the email I receive.

**React Code:**

```
 const handleSendMessage = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(form.current);
        emailjs.sendForm(process.env.REACT_APP_EMAILJS_SERVICE_KEY, process.env.REACT_APP_EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_NAME, form.current, process.env.REACT_APP_EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY)
          .then((result) => {
              console.log(result.text);
          }, (error) => {
              console.log(error.text);
          });
    }

<form ref={form} id='contact-form' onSubmit={handleSendMessage}>
                        <input className='contact-form-input' id='contact-full-name' placeholder='Full Name' type='text' name="name" required/>
                        <label htmlFor='name' className='contact-form-label-name'>Full Name</label>
                        <input className='contact-form-input' id='contact-email-address' placeholder='Email Address' type='email' name='email' required/>
                        <label htmlFor='email' className='contact-form-label-email'>Email Address</label>
                        <input className='contact-form-input' id='contact-subject' placeholder='Subject' type='text' name='subject' required/>
                        <label htmlFor='subject' className='contact-form-label-subject'>Subject</label>
                        <textarea name='message' id='contact-form-message' placeholder='Message' required/>
                        <label htmlFor='message' className='contact-form-label-message'>Message</label>
                        <div className='contact-form-submit-container'>
                            <input type='submit' id='contact-form-submit-btn' name='submit' value='Send Message'/>
                        </div>
</form>
```

**EmailJS Template:**

```
A new message has been sent from the contact page.



Message Senders full name: {{{name}}}

Message Sender's email: {{{email}}}

Message subject: {{{subject}}}

Message: {{{message}}}
```

**Image of email:** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j90yn.png)

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of messing around, I simply changed the **form.current** callback to **e.target** and everything seemed to work.